# CakePHP AJAX call

Tags: ajax, jquery, cakephp

I am using `CakePHP` and this is my first project on this framework. I am going to send the value of an input to `UsersController`'s `check_username()` action. And fill an element having id `na` with the string returned by `check_username()`. So far what I did is:

```
//in my form
<input type="text" name="data[User][username]" style="width: 60%" required="required" id="username" oninput="check_username(this.value)">
<label style="margin-left: 20px; color: red" id="na">Not Available!</label>

//after the form
<script type="text/javascript">
    function check_username(un) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/oes/users/check_username',
            data: {username:un},
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'HTML',
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('#na').html('Checking...');
            },
            success: function (html){
                $('#na').val(html);
            }
        });
    }
</script>

//and my check_username() is
public  function check_username(){
    return 'Test string';
}
```

But this isn't working. Anybody know why or how to modify it so that it works?

Comment: Long live syntax highlighting. You forgot the closing quote after the `#na` in your success callback.

Comment: Edited. But still not working, `beforeSend` is working properly but not `success`.

Comment: set error callback and check error message

Comment: debug level is 2, no error was seen. Even I tested with  `$('#na').val('test...');` still not working.

Comment: Try `$.ajax({...}).fail(function() { console.log(arguments); });` and see if anything gets logged.

Comment: I found nothing using `console.log(arguments)` (never used it before) but found `[object Arguments]` when replaced `console.log(arguments)` with `alert(arguments)`. Now what?

Comment: So there is an error. I think you're looking in the wrong place. You need to check the JavaScript error console in your browser's dev tools. I assume you've been checking server error logs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be problem with your `check_username` controller action. CakePHP-way is to use `JsonView` class to send any data throw XHR (see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html). It allows you to call any action with .json extension (ex.: /oes/users/check_username.json) and get response in serialized JSON format without manual conversion beetween array data and JSON.

This method is recommended for your needs, but not obligated, of course.

Now I think that CakePHP tries to render `check_username` view, but could not do this because you have not specified or created it. Try to change your action code to something like this:

```
public function check_username(){
     $this->autoRender = false;
     echo 'Test string';
}
```

Also, try not to use such code construction in the future.

Comment: Ok, it works. But what type of coding do you suggest if I want to run ajax to check such things?

Comment: It is good practice to use serialized JSON-data in AJAX, so I recommend to use CakePHP JSON View.

Answer (score 2):

CakePHP has a JS Helper to help write aJax functions. The only catch is to include jquery in your head our cake will throw jQuery errors.

Your Form:

```
<?php 
  echo $this->Form->create('User', array('default'=>false, 'id'=>'YourForm'));
  echo $this->Form->input('username');
  echo $this->Form->submit('Check Username');
  echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

The Ajax Function:

```
<?php
  $data = $this->Js->get('#YourForm')->serializeForm(array('isForm' => true, 'inline' => true));
  $this->Js->get('#YourForm')->event(
    'submit',
    $this->Js->request(
      array('action' => 'checkUsername', 'controller' => 'user'),
      array(
        'update' => '#na',
        'data' => $data,
        'async' => true,    
        'dataExpression'=>true,
        'method' => 'POST'
      )
    )
  );
  echo $this->Js->writeBuffer();                                                 
?>
```

The Function in User Controller

```
function checkUsername(){
  $this->autoRender = false;
  //run your query here 

  if ( $username == true ) 
    echo 'Username is taken';
  else
    echo 'Username is not taken';  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many examples through google. [Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_ajax_example.htm) is a good one to visit.